# React. How to populate the form after the login is completed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

I have two react components(SignupDetails.js, BasicInformation.js). SignupDetails is obviously responsible to signup the user, it will get the user information from the form and submit it to the server through axios.

On the server side(backend), if the user already exist, the server will then collect the remain information, such as first name, middle name, etc and then send it back to be collected on the client side.

Back to the client side, now the remain user information which has been returned is then stored in the central store using the redux-reducers and the page is then "redirected" to BasicInformation.js

Now on the BasicInformation.js, mapStateToPros is then executed so I will do have access to the information that has been stored on the central store but then it becomes the problem: I am struggling to show the remain information. This sounds pretty simple but I tried many things on the componentDidUpdate and on the render method but without being successful.

Please find the code below and let me know if you any ideas.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classes from './SignUp.module.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../../store/actions/index';
import Spinner from '../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner'

class SignupDetails extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            email: '',
            password: ''
        };

        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    postDataHandler = () => {
        const data = {
            username: this.state.email,
            email: this.state.email,
            password: this.state.password
        };
        this.props.onSignupDetails(data);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.history.push({pathname: '/signup_details/'})
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.signup_details_success)
            this.props.history.push({pathname: '/basic_information/'})
    }

    render() {
        let errorMessage = null;
        if (this.props.error) {
            errorMessage = (
                <p>{this.props.signup_details_response}</p>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Spinner show={this.props.loading}/>
                <div className={classes.SignUpForm}>
                    {errorMessage}
                    <h3>Take your first step.</h3>

                    <div>
                        <input
                            key="email"
                            name="email"
                            value={this.state.email}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <input
                            key="password"
                            name="password"
                            value={this.state.password}
                            onChange={this.handleInputChange}/>
                    </div>

                    <button className={classes.OkButton} onClick={this.postDataHandler}>Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        signup_details: state.signup.signup_details,
        signup_details_success: state.signup.signup_details_success,
        signup_details_response: state.signup.signup_details_response,
        loading: state.signup.loading,
        error: state.signup.error
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onSignupDetails: (signup_details) => dispatch(actions.signupDetails(signup_details))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SignupDetails);



-----



import React, {Component} from 'react';
import classes from './SignUp.module.css';
import {connect} from 'react-redux'
import * as actions from '../../store/actions/index';
import Spinner from '../../components/UI/Spinner/Spinner'

class BasicInformation extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            first_name: '',
            middle_name: '',
            last_name: '',
            mobile_number: '',
            fund_balance: ''
        }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }

    handleInputChange(event) {
        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        });
    }

    postDataHandler = () => {
        const data = {
            username: this.state.email,
            email: this.state.email,
            first_name: this.state.first_name,
            middle_name: this.state.middle_name,
            last_name: this.state.last_name,
            mobile_number: this.state.mobile_number,
            sfunds: [{balance: this.state.fund_balance}]
        };

        this.props.onSignupBasicInformation(data);
    }

    componentDidUpdate() {
        if (this.props.signup_basic_information_success)
            this.props.history.push({pathname: '/personal_information/'})
    }

    render() {
        let errorMessage = null;
        if (this.props.error) {
            errorMessage = (
                <p>{this.props.signup_basic_information_response}</p>
            );
        }

        return (
            <div>
                <Spinner show={this.props.loading}/>
                <div className={classes.SignUpForm}>
                    {errorMessage}
                    <h3>First we need some basic information</h3>

                    <div><input
                        key="first_name"
                        name="first_name"
                        value={this.state.first_name}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></div>
                    <div><input
                        key="middle_name"
                        name="middle_name"
                        value={this.state.middle_name}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></div>
                    <div><input
                        key="last_name"
                        name="last_name"
                        value={this.state.last_name}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></div>
                    <div><input
                        key="mobile_number"
                        name="mobile_number"
                        value={this.state.mobile_number}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></div>
                    <div><input
                        key="fund_balance"
                        name="fund_balance"
                        value={this.state.fund_balance}
                        onChange={this.handleInputChange}/></div>

                    <button className={classes.OkButton} onClick={this.postDataHandler}>Next</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        signup_details_success: state.signup.signup_details_success,
        signup_details_response: state.signup.signup_details_response,

        signup_basic_information: state.signup.signup_basic_information,
        signup_basic_information_success: state.signup.signup_basic_information_success,
        signup_basic_information_response: state.signup.signup_basic_information_response,

        loading: state.signup.loading,
        error: state.signup.error
    };
};

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
    return {
        onSignupBasicInformation: (basic_information) => dispatch(actions.signupBasicInformation(basic_information))
    };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(BasicInformation);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone wonder, I managed to solve this problem through componentDidMount to set the local state.

```
componentDidMount(){
    if(this.props.smsf_member_details) {
        this.setState({
            first_name: this.props.smsf_member_details.first_name,
            last_name: this.props.smsf_member_details.last_name,
            middle_name: this.props.smsf_member_details.middle_name,
        });
    }
}
```